# Loop through every object with a certain class, performing some css on all objects EXCEPT the object that triggered the event

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

What I  wish to know is how would I modify the below code to apply css to all objects with a specific class EXCEPT the object which triggered the hover event.

```
 $(".back").hover(
    function(){

        $(this).find("span").show();
        $(this).find("span").slideDown("slow");

    },
    function(){
        $(this).find("span").css ("display", "none");

    }
);
```

So at the moment the above code will apply css to the hovered object containing the class '.back'. Whereas I want the opposite, so apply css to all objects with the class '.back' except the one triggering the event.

Now I know it would go along the lines of analysing the current object being looped over, and if that object != to the object triggering the hover then apply the css. But I am unsure of the syntax.

If this doesn't make sense, please don't hesitate to ask me to explain further.

Thanks for any help!

Callum

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [**.not()**](http://api.jquery.com/not/)

```
$(".back").hover(
    function(){

        $('.back').not(this).find("span").show();
        $('.back').not(this).find("span").slideDown("slow");

    },
    function(){
        $('.back').not(this).find("span").hide();

    }
);
```

Comment: Ah thankyou very much! This is a simple yet effective solution, +1!